# How do I make Hudson/Jenkins fail if Sonar thresholds are breached?

Tags: java, hudson, jenkins, metrics, sonarqube

I am using maven to build my java app, Jenkins for CI and Sonar for metrics.

Currently I have a build job that creates the sonar report.  (Triggered via a post-build step in Jenkins.)

I would like to set this up to fail the build if certain thresholds are met - i.e. any major or blocker violations or Complexity more than 1.7.

Any guidance would be appreciated!
 - L

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install the [build breaker](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin) plugin.

Fails your build if the code breaches any of the [alert thresholds](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+profiles#Qualityprofiles-Editalerts) you specify on the project's Sonar quality profile.

## Update

Sonarqube no longer recommends the use of this plugin:

- http://www.sonarqube.org/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/

## Update (2019-02-11)

It appears the product has changed since I wrote this answer 7 years ago

- https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/

Comment: Unfortunately the Build Breaker plugin is unavailable for Sonar 5.2+

Comment: I was using it to fail pull requests with Github... what a shame

Comment: Not being able to break a build, when static analysis fails in Sonar is IMO a deal-breaker on using Sonar.  The only way to ensure that 'code smell's'/'bugs' are not addressed during check'ins is by breaking the build.  Would we put up with not being able to break a build when unit tests fail?  IMO it's the same thing.  Not having this built-in to Sonar gradle plugin bewilders me.  Yes, there is a problem with a synchronous build vs async Sonar processing, but this is an implementation problem.  If Sonar are serious about what they do, this is a must have.

Comment: @Ben I don't disagree. When I wrote this answer 7 years ago the plugin worked perfectly. I would encourage you to take this up with SonarQube

Comment: @Ben  It appears breaking the build is supported in Jenkins pipelines. I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes, sorry my first comment was aimed at SonarQube not yourself :-). Thanks, I saw that Jenkins support.  Alas, we use TeamCity.  Cheers

Comment: Sonar have updated their advice with new suggestions: https://blog.sonarsource.com/breaking-the-sonarqube-analysis-with-jenkins-pipelines/

Comment: last link reports 404 for me

Answer (score 2):

Use Jenkins [Quality Gates Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quality+Gates+Plugin), which fails the build if the predefined sonar quality gates are not green.

1. **Plugin ID** quality-gates
2. **Latest Release** 2.5
3. **Latest Release Date** May 17, 2016
4. **Required Core** 1.625.3

This plugin will stop a job when a quality gate measures is detected.