# Findbugs & Ant - Stop the build for particular violation

Tags: java, ant, findbugs

I am building my application using ANT and I am checking my code for any **Findbugs** violations.

Now, my objective is to stop the build whenever my code contains particular findbug violation.

Is this possible using ANT & Findbugs?

N.B. Preferably not to write to any custom class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [warningsProperty attribute on your findbugs task](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html) to set a property for any warnings:

```
<findbugs ... warningsProperty="findbugsFailure"/>
```

and fail `task` if warnings are produced:

```
<fail if="findbugsFailure">
```

For example:

```
  <property name="findbugs.home" value="/export/home/daveho/work/findbugs" />

  <target name="findbugs" depends="jar">

    <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}"
              output="xml"
              outputFile="bcel-fb.xml" 
              warningsProperty="findbugsFailure">
      <auxClasspath path="${basedir}/lib/Regex.jar" />
      <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src/java" />
      <class location="${basedir}/bin/bcel.jar" />
    </findbugs>

    <fail if="findbugsFailure">

  </target>
```

Comment: You might want to split FindBugs into two runs, one for warnings that should stop the build, and one for warnings that should not.

Comment: Also please note that the warningsProperty only seems to be set correctly if "setExeitCode" is set to "true" (which is the default).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative idea (and worth the effort) would be to integrate [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) into your [ANT build](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task) process.

Sonar integrates Findbugs (and checkstyle and PMD) and you can centrally configure it to fail the build against any set of criteria using it's build breaker plugin. See:

[How do I make Hudson/Jenkins fail if Sonar thresholds are breached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942960/how-do-i-make-hudson-jenkins-fail-if-sonar-thresholds-are-breeched/8949974#8949974)