# How to configure hudson to fail if code coverage is lower than before the build?

Tags: maven, hudson

Is there a way to configure maven build on hudson to fail if code coverage is lower than previous build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to this question

- [How do I make Hudson/Jenkins fail if Sonar thresholds are breached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942960/how-do-i-make-hudson-jenkins-fail-if-sonar-thresholds-are-breeched/8949974#8949974)

There's a Hudson plugin for [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). Code coverage is one of the standard metrics and you can define thresholds against any quality metric.