# Failing a jenkins build for coverage going down

Tags: jenkins

I would like to break a jenkins build if the code coverage has gone down from the previous successful build. I have seen a previous answer here where the suggestion was to use the groovy plugin to access the jenkins api, compare current coverage with the previous coverage & fail the build if it drops.

This I believe is exactly what I am looking for but I am not sure where in the jenkins api I can pull this information from?

I am using the Cobertura plugin to run code coverage analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that would be available if you used Sonar to host your metrics.

- [How do I make Hudson/Jenkins fail if Sonar thresholds are breached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942960/how-do-i-make-hudson-jenkins-fail-if-sonar-thresholds-are-breeched/8949974#8949974)

Much more flexible solution and Sonar is a very useful tool in its own right, with a plugin available for Jenkins.

Comment: Yes I have looked at this but unfortunately sonar is a centrally managed service where this plugin is not installed & won’t be in the near future